# Must symbol be unique in Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symbols, state-machine

When we use symbol in Rails (ex :user, :type...), must they be unique in the project ? For instance, can we name a state (in a state machine) the same as an attribute ? Or is there a risk of collision ?

Comment: They don't have to be unique in project, but the attributes/states (in state machine) usually have to be unique among one model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Symbol objects represent names and some strings inside the Ruby interpreter. They are generated using the :name and :"string" literals syntax, and by the various to_sym methods. The **same Symbol object will be created for a given name or string for the duration of a program's execution**, regardless of the context or meaning of that name.

Answering your question: there is no risk of collision.